# Slim Framework proper htaccess setup with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I want to make an api with slim. it would be on my "tools" subdomain in a directory called api.

```
http://tools.fifaguide.com/api
```

What should my .htaccess file look like?

Currently my .htaccess is located in my Wordpress directory (html -> .htaccess), and it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

//my part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/index.php
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) http://tools.fifaguide.com/api/index.php [L]

//wordpress part
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem with this is that when I try

```
 http://tools.fifaguide.com/api/hello/steve
```

I imediately get redirected back to api/index.php instead of staying on /api/hello/steve and having the results shown.

Its seems like wordpress is making this happen, but how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ api/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```